# Is there a software alternative in Ubuntu for iSpy in windows (multiple Web cam recording software[DVR] )?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, webcam

I use iSpy in windows for recording multiple webcams and from multiple audio sources i.e, using the PC as a DVR. Is there a software for Ubuntu that can do that? I need advanced features like motion detection and if possible number plate detection and face detection (iSpy has them). And also the feature of recording audio if it gets above a certain level.

Comment: Zoneminder is for advanced users sometimes even requiring programming knowledge

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I presume from what you are asking you are looking for Ubuntu video surveillance software. 
Both Xeoma, zoneminder, and Shinobi can be used for this.

Shinobi can be found here https://moeiscool.github.io/Shinobi/

You can get Xeoma from the software centre but reading the comments the version available for free is trial not fully functional software. You will need to upgrade and pay for the full version which the software prompts you to do.

Zoneminder is another Linux video surveillance solution also available from the software centre. for a more up to date version you will need to compile from source http://www.zoneminder.com/downloads

### ZoneMinder

website address http://www.zoneminder.com/

**Feature List**
 - Runs on any Linux distribution!

- Supports video, USB and network cameras.
- Support Pan/Tilt/Zoom cameras, extensible to add new control protocols.
- Built on standard tools, C++, perl and PHP.
- Uses high performance MySQL database.
- High performance independent video capture and analysis daemons allowing high failure redundancy.
- Multiple Zones (Regions Of Interest) can be defined per camera. Each can have a different sensitivity or be ignored altogether.
- Large number of configuration options allowing maximum performance on any hardware.
  User friendly web interface allowing full control of system or cameras as well as live views and event replays.
- Supports live video in mpeg video, multi-part jpeg and stills formats.
- Supports event replay in mpeg video, multi-part jpeg, stills formats, along with statistics detail.
- User defined filters allowing selection of any number of events by combination of characteristics in any order.
- Event notification by email or SMS including attached still images or video of specific events by filter.
- Automatic uploading of matching events to external FTP storage for archiving and data security.
- Includes bi-directional X.10 (home automation protocol) integration allowing X.10 signals to control when video is captured and for motion detection to trigger X.10 devices.
- Highly partitioned design allow other hardware interfacing protocols to be added easily for support of alarm panels etc.
- Multiple users and user access levels Multi-language support with many languages already included Full control script support allowing most tasks to be automated or added to other applications.
- Support external triggering by 3rd party applications or equipment.
  xHTML mobile/cellular phone access allowing access to common functions
  iPhone interface available

**Screenshots** http://www.zoneminder.com/screenshots

### Xeoma

http://felenasoft.com/en/

Licence costs on per camera basis up to 1024 cameras http://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/buy/

**Typical applications:**

- Object monitoring in non-working hours (office, store, warehouse)
- Security surveillance (perimeter security monitoring, car, etc.)
- Staff monitoring (industry workers, office employees, caregivers and home staff)
- Monitoring of activity of children and office workers on computer, control over visited sites
- Pet surveillance
- Watching machinery in industries

**Camera/sources processing:**

- Compatible with any webcams, cctv cams, including wireless cctv cameras
- Supports IP-cameras (including H.264, JPEG/MJPEG, MPEG-4, PTZ and ONVIF, wireless cams, i.e. perfect both for wired and wireless cctv)
- Works with world webcams
- Screen captures from all monitors simultaneously

**Professional surveillance made easy:**

- Free rebranding of Xeoma
- Group settings of modules
- Xeoma Cloud Service
- Creating a surveillance network of Xeoma servers by using web server
- Shared access rights (user permissions)
- Multi-Server and Multi-Client connection architecture for video surveillance of any size
- Password protection of settings
- Fullscreen view
- PTZ inversion

**Remote access:**

- Remote view via mobile devices
- Online view of all cameras with sound
- Full remote access to settings, archive and cameras
- Internet broadcasting
- Remote access even with dynamic IP address

**Motion detector:**

S - etting up of zone(s) of any size and shape to monitor for motion

- Visual motion detection: frame of preview box changes its color at motion detection and indicates time of the last detected movement
- Setting up maximum object size to be ignored and sensitivity level of sensor
- Pre-record option to store several seconds preceding motion detection
- Post-record to continue recording after the event has finished
- Record delay
- Enhanced algorithm to avoid false alarms caused by pets or weather changes

**Archive:**

- Adjustable maximum size of archive and compression rate of images stored to archive
- Loop recording
- Possibility to store archive onto different HDDs
- Built-in media player with adjustable speed of playback
- Export of a selected extract right from the viewer

**Notifications and reactions:**

- Text message (SMS) sending
- E-mail notifications (with attached JPEG images and MJPEG videos)
- Event-triggered pop-up window
- Sound alarm
- Running a specified program that will receive the path to the current image
- FTP server upload of images and videos with sound
- Saving files to the specified path with cyclic recording

**All high-demand features:**

- Hidden mode of work
- H.264, MPEG-4, MP4 and MJPEG video formats
- Marking (embedded time and date, or custom text stamp)
- Scheduler, setting up when system's components are to start/end work
- Adjustable volume of sound in preview mode
- Duplicating of chains
- Various view modes
- Automatic slide show of real-time images
- 1-click-easy updates
- New versions notifications

**Xeoma advantages:**

- No installation needed
- No admin rights required
- Simple additional settings
- Flexible control like in a children's construction set
- Innovative intuitive graphical interface
- Available in English, Spanish, Italian, Brazilian Portuguese, German, Dutch, Danish, Romanian, Turkish, Hungarian, Finnish, Polish, Ukrainian and Russian languages

**Screenshots**

http://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/screenshots/

Comment: Note that xeoma requires VM installs to have internet access 247 or be tied to a licence server that requires internet access 247. Which means you can't block their access. Big drawback for users who run most of their software on virtual machines. https://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/description/#activation_virtual

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't like the Linux alternatives (I certainly don't), iSpy does run without problems in a Virtual Box, providing you set the network mode of that box to 'Bridged'.

Comment: Where did you get a Windows .iso for Vritual Box?

Comment: Vagrant or you can download free trials and just format and install again