# Is there a ONVIF Device Manager alternative for Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, video

Is there a ONVIF Device Manager like xeoma alternative for Ubuntu 16.04LTS?
`sudo apt install xeoma` from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xeoma/) does not work anymore.

**Update**

27/March/2017: Referring to the first answer about Zoneminder. It is up to date now. You can find them on [github](https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/) and docs [here](https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installationguide/index.html). I successfully paired 2 cameras with it running on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

**Update: Available Full-featured CCTV Software for Ubuntu**

- [Xeoma](https://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/download/) and [docs](https://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/articles/) Tested paid version, ok for watching live feeds, archive playback buggy on Ubuntu 18.04LTS Server.
- [Shinobi](https://shinobi.video) and [docs](https://shinobi.video/docs/)
- [Zoneminder](https://zoneminder.com/downloads/) and [docs](https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- Feature list for some [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/347780/190762)

Comment: https://github.com/RogerHardiman/onvif-audit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[xeoma](http://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/download/) has a tar.gz installer. [32-bit](http://felenasoft.com/_images/free_download_1_en.jpg) and [64-bit](http://felenasoft.com/xeoma/downloads/xeoma_linux64.tgz). It only has 1 file and worked straight out of the box for me.

Mind though: it is payware (and monthly even, if I read the license correctly).

Open source and free: [zoneminder](https://www.zoneminder.com/downloads/) They have a warning: don't use our repos since they are out of date and to use their [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~iconnor/+archive/ubuntu/zoneminder). Pity it has not been updated to 16.04 so is out of date as well ( :P ).

Comment: Note that xeoma requires VM installs to have internet access 247 or be tied to a licence server that requires internet access 247.  Not private enough for me and the reason i'm looking for a replacement NVR is to eliminate another hardware box so buying a dedicated machine for this is out. https://felenasoft.com/xeoma/en/description/#activation_virtual

Comment: New ppa https://launchpad.net/~iconnor/+archive/ubuntu/zoneminder-1.32

Answer (score 3):

You can try Lingodigits' ONVIF Device Tool, has Ubuntu 16.04 64bit version
ONVIF Device Tool passed ONVIF Client Test Tool v16.01 and free to download.

http://www.lingodigit.com/onvif_nvc.html

Comment: I tried to install onvif-device-tool, but from deb file, and I get a following error:  `onvif-device-tool: error while loading shared libraries: libvlccore.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's the best option I guess altough you would need a docker container to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Shinobi:

- https://gitlab.com/Shinobi-Systems/ShinobiCE (Community Edition)
- http://shinobi.video/pro/ (Professional)

Comment: Is it possible to have import parts of those links added to your answer

Comment: I tried Shinobi. Looks nice, buggy non-intuitive interface (features spread across different logins (/, /admin, /super) instead of centralized with permission based view changes), documentation unorganized.... read https://github.com/PharkMillups/beautiful-docs, getting help on discord is sporadic and unorganized. The efforts there would be better suited in a traditional forum where questions and responses aren't overlapping and easily lost, $75/mo for pro if you want help as appose to paying $35+ (4cams) perpetual xeoma licence (best software i've seen). Shinobi was a frustrating experience.